# Best way to design a Comparator accessing String fields that might be empty or null

Tags: java, string, null, comparison

I have to sort a Collection by different String attributes that might be empty (`""`) or even `null`. Both values are allowed and have to be treated equally.

I solved this issue by using a method, that checks each String for `null` and returns an empty String, when `null` is found.

---

So far my Comparator looks basicly like this

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {

    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        // ... some logical stuff like e.g.
        return rein(o1.getSomeValue()).compareTo(rein(o2.getSomeValue());
    }

    private String rein(String str) {
        return str == null ? "" : str;          
    }
}
```

I wonder if this design is considered to be ok or if there are reason against it? If it is not ok, what else may I do to fulfil my requirements? All those (in most cases unneccessary) function calls looks ugly to me, as we are talking about approximately 1/1000 cases. So I wonder if there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong here. If you omit 'rein' method you will get NullPointerException in case when o1.getSomeValue() returns null. So this check is necessary for correct compare method working. It's hard to imagine more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. It's just that those cases are really rare, so I thought that there might be a better solotion. Maybe risking an NPE and catch it to perform different logic, but to misuse exceptions for the process seems ugly to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 one can rewrite it a bit more concise in functional style using [Comparator.comparing(keyExtractor)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) and other factory methods from [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#method.summary) to chain / compose comparators. But you still have to handle the `null` case otherwise a `NullPointerException` will arise.

- When `null` and `""` are treated equally:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

Comparator<MyObject> bySomeValue =
    comparing(obj -> rein(obj.getSomeValue()));
```

Note: `nullToEmpty()` would be a more suitable name than `rein()`.

- `null` ordering can be explicitly specified by available [nullsFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) or [nullsLast()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-) decorators

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;
import static java.util.Comparator.nullsLast;

Comparator<MyObject> bySomeValue =
    comparing(MyObject::getSomeValue, nullsLast(naturalOrder()));
```